# Add Array record to Meta Post

Tags: array, post-meta

I am trying to add the following array into the meta post table

```
"a:2:{s:11:"target";a:1:{i:0;a:1:{i:1;a:3:{s:5:"param";s:13:"page_selected";s:8:"operator";s:2:"==";s:5:"value";a:5:{i:3001;s:13:"Service Areas";i:1098;s:19:"Water Slide Rentals";i:672;s:15:"Chairs & Tables";i:205;s:4:"Home";i:1401;s:29:"Bounce House Rental Armada MI";}}}}s:15:"sgpb-conditions";N;}"
```

I broke down the array as follows

```
a:2:{  ##  ARRAY 1 [3 ELEMENTS]<br>
 -->KEY&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;VALUE 1-1<br>
s:11:"target";&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;a:1:{ ##  ARRAY 2 [2 ELEMENTS]<br><br>
 -->KEY&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;VALUE 1-2 <br>
   i:0;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;a:1:{    ##  ARRAY 3 [2 ELEMENTS]<br><br>
 -->KEY&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;VALUE 2-1 <br>
   i:1;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;a:3:{ ##  ARRAY 3 [4 ELEMENTS]<br><br>
 -->KEY&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;VALUE 3-1 <br>
s:5:"param";&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;s:13:"page_selected";<br><br>
 -->KEY&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;VALUE 3-2 <br>
s:8:"operator";&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;s:2:"==";<br><br>
 -->KEY&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;VALUE 3-3 <br>
s:5:"value";&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;a:5:{ ##  ARRAY 4 [6 ELEMENTS]<br><br>
 -->KEY&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;VALUE 4-1 <br>
i:3001;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;s:13:"Service Areas";<br><br>
 -->KEY&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;VALUE 4-2 <br>
i:1098;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;s:19:"Water Slide Rentals";<br><br>
 -->KEY&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;VALUE 4-3 <br>
i:672;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;s:15:"Chairs & Tables";<br><br>
 -->KEY&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;VALUE 4-4 <br>
i:205;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;s:4:"Home";<br><br>
 -->KEY&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;VALUE 4-5 <br>
i:1401;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;s:29:"Bounce House Rental Armada MI";<br><br>

} <!-- ENDS ARRAY 5 --><br>
} <!-- ENDS ARRAY 4 --><br>
} <!-- ENDS ARRAY 3 --><br>
} <!-- ENDS ARRAY 2 --><br>
s:15:"sgpb-conditions";N;}  <!-- ENDS ARRAY 1 --><br>
```

^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

## NOT SURE HOW THIS TIES IN

my question is about
First issue I am having is a complete understanding of the array. Not sure how the last values tie into an array. Also, an Array is zero based correct?

Here is the code I have created so far to add the array, which is not creating the array correctly.

```
"<?php<br>
$poddata = Array(<br>
'sgpb-target',<br>
Array (<br>
    1 => Array(<br>
'param' => 'page_selected',<br>
'operator' => '==',<br>
'value' => Array(<br>
                3001 => 'Service Areas',<br>
                1098 => 'Water Slide Rentals',<br>
                672 => 'Chairs & Tables',<br>
                1401 => 'Bounce House Rental Armada MI',<br>
                676 => 'Mobile Gaming Trucks'<br>
                ))));<br>
<br>
update_post_meta(6668, 'poddata', $poddata);<br>
?>"
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: Why does your last block of code have `<br>` tags in it?

Comment: Bad post editing, I needed to wrap it in [code][/code] tags, and not use html tags to format the post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That original value is a [serialised](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) array. If you want to see the original array you can use the `unserialize()` function, or a site like https://www.unserialize.com. The problem is that this isn't working for your Array, because the serialised value is invalid.

The problem is here:

```
s:11:"target"
```

"Target" is 6 letters, so this needs to be:

```
s:6:"target"
```

This wouldn't happen if you were properly serialising and unserialising in PHP, but it's an easy mistake to make if you're trying to manually edit the data. Generally it's a bad idea to try and edit serialised data by hand.

Anyway, I assume that you want to insert a *valid* array, so when you fix that issue and then unserialise it, it looks like this:

```
array(
    'target' => array(
        0 => array (
            1 => array(
                'param'    => 'page_selected',
                'operator' => '==',
                'value'    => array(
                    3001 => 'Service Areas',
                    1098 => 'Water Slide Rentals',
                    672  => 'Chairs & Tables',
                    205  => 'Home',
                    1401 => 'Bounce House Rental Armada MI',
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),
    'sgpb-conditions' => NULL,
)
```

Comment: I did try to manual recreate the array and manual inject it into the database, but like you said bad idea. Than I found  "update_post_meta" which did insert a clean array but structured incorrectly.
The array structure you provided worked perfect! Thanks for your help and cleaning up my post.